# Formula for some specific polynomials

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I have the following problem:

> Given the polynomial $$ P_n (x_1, ..., x_k) = x_1 ^ n + \cdots + x_k ^ n $$ I would like to give an explicit formula (that depends on $ k, n $) to write to $ P_n (x_1, ..., x_k) $ in terms of $ \sigma_1 (x_1, ..., x_k), ..., \sigma_n (x_1, ..., x_k) $ (with $\sigma_i (x_1 ,. .., x_n)$ the $i$th-elementary symmetric polynomial on $ x_1, ..., x_n $), that is, I would like to find a formula for $ s_n $, where $$ P_n (x_1, ..., x_k) = s_n (\sigma_1 (x_1, ..., x_k), ..., \sigma_n (x_1, ..., x_k)) $$

For example:

- $s_1 (x_1,...,x_k) = \sigma_1 (x_1,...,x_n)$
- $s_2 (x_1,...,x_k) = \sigma_1^2 (x_1,...,x_n) - 2\sigma_2 (x_1,...,x_n)$
- $s_3 (x_1,...,x_k) = \sigma_1^3 (x_1,...,x_n) +3\sigma_3 (x_1,...,x_n) - 3 \sigma_1 (x_1,...,x_n) \sigma_2 (x_1,...,x_n)$

Does anyone know how to attack this problem or have any hint?

I already tried induction and recursion but I didn't get anywhere, I don't know if my calculations are wrong

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_power_sums_in_terms_of_elementary_symmetric_polynomials

Comment: Or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities

Comment: Have you looked at those links, Erick?

Comment: Are you still here, Erick?

Comment: Sorry @GerryMyerson, I already looked those links and they are just what I need, thanks to you and Gary

Comment: Good. You could write up an answer to your question then, and post it.

Comment: You could do that today.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.